# Como pasar un string metido en una variable Ejm: let x = "1+5" en javascript

Tags: javascript

con parseInt he probado para pero solo me coge el primer numero

Gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], si puedes colocar un ejemplo completo y verificable sería mas fácil ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con pasar un string metido en una variable? Ahora mismo no queda demasiado claro lo que quieres resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas necesitando es `eval()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval

En el ejemplo que mencionas en el titulo del post seria:

```
x = "1+5"
result = eval("("+x+")");
```